# Database table with dynamic rows and columns

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm going to make an app that gets String person names by EditText then save them in a table1 that has one column in database. 
Also there's another table2 that has some columns equal to number of person names in table1 and rows are person's scores (integer).
I have: "MainActivity" that shows table2, "AddPersonActivity" that shows table1 and allows user to add persons, "AddScoreActivity" that allows user to insert scores for each person, "dbHelper" class that manage my database. 
I need AddScoreActivity to dynamically show EditText for each person and dbHelper to put them in the correct place in table2.
Since I'm new in Android, could any body give me an aidea or example so that user can insert as much as person it wants.

Comment: Please improve the writing of this question. I could not understand it.

Comment: Let's say I want a table that number of rows and columns would be defined by user input then the app is going to display the table graphically. Storing data in database is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

On typical relational databases you cannot add columns dynamically.

Having said that, some databases (for example PostgreSQL) implement the [`array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/arrays.html) data type. If a column is of the array type, then it can contain multiple values in it. You can even have multiple-dimension arrays. For example, this is a typical case:

```
create table person (
  id int primary key not null,
  properties text[]
);
```

Each row on this table includes an id, and zero or many property values stored in an array.

Most often than not, if you have this kind of requirement you'll use a higher normal form by separating the table in two as in:

```
create table person (
  id int primary key not null
);

create table person_property (
  value text,
  person_id int not null,
  constraint fk_prop_person foreign key (person_id) 
    references person (id)
);
```

This way is easier to manage data. In the second structure:

- You don't need to instantiate a full new array when it runs out of elements and you need to add one more.
- SQL queries are much easier to write.
- In general, inserting/updating/deleting properties is very simple compared to the solution that uses arrays.